# Updating installation

Tags: c#, dll, installation

If we give set up to the user then there is a  possibility of coming changes in the code for the set up we had given to the user then we have to make set up again and then we will have to give the set up to the user, then it is not problem but user has to uninstall that set up and has to install new set up again, that is the problem then is there any other option to that ?

I am asking this question because in a application there is a chance to come changes in only one dll of the application then is there is any other option that we make the changes in that dll and give to the user and user has to update only that dll and not has to uninstall whole setup and reinstall whole setup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net dlls don't need to be registered so why dont you make a small update program that would simply replace the updated dll. No need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: if user will update the new dll provided by us, then will it ok and run the application perfectly because I think if this is possible then it is best idea ?

Comment: as long as the new dll does not cause conflict there is no reason why it should not work. I have done this with deployed web apps (a bit different than desktop) and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking for a better deployment solution
for .NET based applications?

In that case I suggest you take a look at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx).
Visual Studio has ClickOnce support out of the box.

Basicaly you deploy the applications through some medium, for example via the internet,
and whenever you push a new update the customer will have the option of upgrading automatically, of you can even have your software update in the background.

If you do not want to use ClickOnce, the other option is to use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).
This will allow you to extend your application with so called add-ons.
These add-ons are basically classes that are loaded from assemblies at runtime.This means you could have a running application using version 1.0 of a certain assembly and even while the application is running the user could replace an assembly and the software would be up to date.

So either you use clickonce to update the entire app automatically,
or you break your application up into smaller parts, load those parts using MEF and have an installer that simply replaces parts on the target system.

Comment: But MEF can not be used in 4.0, is it ?

Comment: MEF can be used in 3.5 (separate download) and it's included by default in 4.0 (System.ComponentModel.Composition.*)

Answer (score 0):

When we run our application a log in window appears where a valid user have to provide his credentials to get in (Old stuff!). As they put them in and after successful sign up we fire up a `web service` request sending the client application meta (version, operating system, etc.). That web service is hosted on our domain. That web service struck to a default function where it query to database to get the information of the latest (or stable) release of the system and then we compare it with the information we got from a client application and send back the comparison. The receive data is a bit value which fall into a case of message window like if this is an older version client application pop up a window allow to download the newer version of the application (or the newer version is available but not compatible with your operating system etc)

We do few more stuff on successful sign up (like License Key Verification). Why after successful sign up 'cause only valid user have the right to stuck our `web service`